# pagehide event on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, page-lifecycle

I am desperately trying to make this work on Chrome (fine on Firefox)

```
window.addEventListener(
  "pagehide",
  function() {
    console.log("pagehide");
  },
  { capture: true }
);
```

now this triggers on page reload, but there is no way it works when pressing forward or back button leads to another website.

PS I have found a bunch of issues here [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&q=pagehide&can=2) but I am not sure if and which of them may apply.

Comment: You can try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event popstate event for that purpose.

Comment: thanks @shashank but "A popstate event is dispatched to the window each time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document."

Comment: I have the same issue on chromium and was able to narrow down this "bug" to the following situations:
- chrome 69 onward (maybe 70, don't remember exactly), and
- navigations cross-site or between http / https.

Comment: **unload** events should be fine for your scenario. It works nicely on page reload for major browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Edge. "**pagehide**" is a messy API written specifically for IOS safari. Believe me we use it heavily on timeonsite tracker for unload, refresh and forward events. It only fails on IOS devices where they recommend "pagehide" for this.

Comment: @clivend Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm currently encountering the same bug. Firefox honors pagehide but Chrome does not. I need to call these to clean up functioning code

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out why there is no "pagehide" in the console when navigating away from a page by entering some URL in the browser or using back/forward buttons. 
Actually, there is an issue with writing to the console on pagehide. I had an API call inside that event callback and it was working fine.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=472282

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but maybe not the way you expect. Simple way of testing it:

```
window.addEventListener('pagehide', function() {
  window.open('https://google.com');
});
```

Any time the page is hidden with a refresh or back/forward navigation, you should have a new Google tab.

Comment: thanks @Darren but unfortunately that does not happen :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.addEventListener('pagehide', function (event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
      // If the event's persisted property is `true` the page is about
      // to enter the Back-Forward Cache, which is also in the frozen state
    } else {
      // If the event's persisted property is not `true` the page is about to be unloaded.
    }
  },
    { capture: true }
  );
```

> "Several browsers implement a Back-Forward Cache, and the Page Lifecycle API classifies cached pages as being in the frozen state. Since this API is brand new, these browsers do not yet implement the freeze and resume events, though this state can still be observed via the pagehide and pageshow events."

[Article on Page Lifecycle API - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#managing-cross-browsers-differences)

Comment: Just a note: If that last paragraph is a quotation from some website, you should really provide the link, along with the quote (and format the paragraph as a blockquote).